# ModelClass Data passing

Tags: ios

I have two ViewControllers and i need to pass data between the ViewControllers using Model Class Concept.

All i need to know is
Why and how is it used? What is the advantage? The technical writing from the book I'm reading makes it hard to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to study the model-view-controller design pattern to understand the why we need to create model class to hold the data and passing the data around view controllers.
Model-View-Controller is key design pattern in most of the languages[Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)

Properties is the design pattern in objective c and swift which is helpful for sharing data among classes.
[Properties in ios](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties)

I suggest you to study all the design pattern which help you for understating the objective basic 
[ios Design Pattern](https://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns)